# Is it not possible to do a repository install for Squeak in Ubuntu derivatives anymore, independent from Scratch?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I noticed there is a squeak-vm in the repositories from Linux Mint 20.1  /Ubuntu 20.04, and so I tried to install it, to see how much of the knowledge I'm acquiring in a [Pharo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharo) course is transferable to [Squeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeak):

```
user@user-Standard:~$ apt-cache search squeak
squeak-plugins-scratch - Squeak plugins for the Scratch programming environment
squeak-plugins-scratch-dbg - Squeak plugins for the Scratch programming environment - debug
squeak-vm - virtual machine for Smalltalk
etoys - media-rich model, simulation construction kit and authoring tool
etoys-doc - documentation for Etoys
user@user-Standard:~$ sudo apt install squeak-vm
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
The following additional packages will be installed:
  scratch
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  scratch squeak-vm
0 pacotes atualizados, 2 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 8 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 25,6 MB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 48,8 MB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] S
Obter:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 squeak-vm amd64 1:4.10.2.2614-8build1 [510 kB]
Obter:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 scratch all 1.4.0.6~dfsg1-6 [25,1 MB]
Baixados 25,6 MB em 15s (1.660 kB/s)                                           
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado squeak-vm.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 316417 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.
)
A preparar para desempacotar .../squeak-vm_1%3a4.10.2.2614-8build1_amd64.deb ...
A descompactar squeak-vm (1:4.10.2.2614-8build1) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado scratch.
A preparar para desempacotar .../scratch_1.4.0.6~dfsg1-6_all.deb ...
A descompactar scratch (1.4.0.6~dfsg1-6) ...
Configurando squeak-vm (1:4.10.2.2614-8build1) ...
Configurando scratch (1.4.0.6~dfsg1-6) ...
A processar 'triggers' para gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-3) ...
A processar 'triggers' para shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para desktop-file-utils (0.24+linuxmint1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

Now the curious thing is that it installs Scratch as well, even if I just requested Squeak.

When I look into the menu, it shows both Squeak and Scratch:

[image]

When I choose Squeak, a empty image selection screen is shown:

[image]

If I click the empty selection, nothing happens. It appears the squeak-vm is only a dependency for Scratch, and it's not possible to install it from the repository as a independent environment anymore. Am I right, or did I just do something wrong in the install process?

Comment: I don't use Linux Mint/Ubuntu so can't check.  I think you are missing a squeak image which you need in order to run the environment.  Try to get it here - https://squeak.org/downloads/

Comment: @tukan , in the selection screen there is no option to navigate my folders to select a downloaded image.

Comment: Hard to say as I don't have it installed.  I imagine there would be a configuration file where you could direct your image directory to proper location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that the debian package (and since Ubuntu is derived from Debian as best I recall, I infer the Ubuntu package has the same issues) was created a long time ago and ... pretty much abandoned. Right now I believe it installs a vm built from the old-style interpreter sources, not the modern dynamic translator system.

We (the Squeak community) are working on improving this.

In the meantime it is much better to download packages from [www.squeak.org](http://www.squeak.org)

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded the current release of squeak and edited the app location, squeak.sh; that worked out.

[image]

Comment: +1, but did you download it directly from the project site, or from the package manager and repositories of the linux distribution? I was trying a package manager install.

Comment: i've also downloaded it through the terminal, the same happened

Comment: I tried to download a image from the site, and change the working directory in the launcher to the path where I extracted the image, as shown in your screenshot, but it still didn't work.